# Re-render Gutenberg block without calling setAttributes?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Is it possible to make a Gutenberg component to re-render without having to call `props.setAttributes()`?

When my Gutenberg block is displayed, I'm doing an AJAX request to look if there is new data available and showing a "Loading..." text. If there is no data available, I just want to remove the "Loading..." text. But how do you do that without calling `props.setAttributes()` first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blocks of Gutenberg are actually React Components and there are two major ways to trigger rendering in React one is to change `props` and the other one is to change `state`.

In Gutenberg `props` is equivalent to `attributes` but state is state. So you can add `isLoading` attribute on `attributes` with default value of `true` and when you receive ajax response then you can switch this to `false`.

As technically `isLoading` is not a part of your block attribute so my suggestion to you is to prefer `state`. Please note that you can only define state in Class Components of React or by using hooks in functional components (on react v16 and above).

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for! I didn't realise that attributes are props instead of state. I'm now using state to manage the loader.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to manage and update the state? I had no luck accessing it, the only thing that works is `props.setAttributes()` but it leaves clutter in my attributes I don't wish to persist.

Comment: OK now I have `props.setState({whatever: Date.now()});` changing the `props.whatever` but my block isn't refreshing.

Comment: Ooh I actually need to make use of it :D

Answer (score 1):

I took Mehmood Ahmad's answer as a pointer and decided to expand this state idea. So the problem with refreshing the block using
`props.setAttributes({something: Date.now()});`
is that this attribute will persist perpeutally. You can check that it pollutes your real attributes if you switch to Code Editor view, it'll be in that HTML comment.

So, the object you use in your `wp.blocks.registerBlockType`'s `edit` needs to be built upon or composed with `wp.compose.withState`. Since I also wanted to use another [HOC](https://zendev.com/2018/07/24/higher-order-components-react-gutenberg.html), `wp.data.withSelect`, I chose the [compose](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-compose/) way.

```
window.wp.compose.compose(
    wp.data.withSelect( /* ... */ ),
    wp.compose.withState({something: ''})
)(function (props) {
 // Actually make use of props.something
});
```

Then wherever needed, for example in a click handler, you update it with:

```
props.setState({something: Date.now()});
```

It'll re-render the block without persisting the value. You must use `props.something` or nothing will happen.

Comment: Is this implemented in a plugin somewhere? I tried to understand this but I don't know what to set for  /* ... */ in withSelect and what you mean with to actually make use of it.

Comment: IIRC in WP Real Media Library if you inspect the block's HTML there is an attribute that doesn't do anything (date/timestamp) just for this rerender.

Comment: Well, the block's HTML does not really help. I would like to understand how to use the state and not sending an attribute to my server side rendered block. Because the result is changed content in the editor when the user tries to save the post. 
Here is my current solution with an attribute: https://github.com/mtoensing/simpletoc/blob/master/src/edit.js#L35